# How to import two versions of the same go module?

Tags: go, go-modules

I have this problem:

- Module A imports module X v0.1.0
- Module B imports module X v0.2.0
- I import both A and B in my project.

Golang picks out X v0.2.0 and calls it good. But it is not good. v0.1 and v0.2 are different enough that A breaks and my project doesn't compile.

**What options do I have to fix this?**

The offical go stance seems to be "developers of X were doing it wrong and should've released a major version after breaking changes". But that doesn't help the current situation.

I can't find discussions of practical solutions.

---

**Further information**

- The above is a simplification, A and B have a couple more dependencies that also depend on X.
- This project needs to be maintainable by a group of people. So updating A and B to new versions is ideally straightforwards.
- This is security-critical code so subtle bugs from mismatched dependencies are a concern.

Things I've tried:

- Forking A and X, changing the import paths throughout, and updating A's `go.mod`. It works but makes updates to those modules slow and error prone.
- Copy and pasting the required code out of A and X to avoid importing it. Also slow and error prone.
- Did a deep dive into creative applications of `go mod vendor`, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the official answer is the answer; you can't import two different versions where the version numbers indicate they should be backward-compatible. Forking is possibly your best solution, or if at all possible, using a different package that isn't managed so poorly.

Comment: As @Adrian says you can't do this when the import path is the same. I was able to do something similar when importing the same package with *different* import paths - namely `github.com/allegro/bigcache` and `github.com/allegro/bigcache/v2`. Using Go interfaces I could switch - via a runtime config - between either version (as `v2` was sporadically crashing). Depending on the coverage of the API you are using, an interface may help you do something similar with a "forked" version.

Comment: Technically the developers of X are **not** doing it wrong, because a `v0` major version,  according to semver, *is for initial development. Anything may change at any time. The public API should not be considered stable*. Instead it's modules that import libraries in `v0` that do so at their own risk.

Answer (score 5):

You can, for example, create local copies of the both modules and use replace directives along with a pseudo major versions to import multiple versions of the same repo using different tags:

```golang
replace moduleX/v1010 => ./src/moduleX/0.1.0

replace moduleX/v1020 => ./src/moduleX/0.2.0
```

Then in your project would use either of the versions as needed:

```golang
import (
  moduleX_010 "moduleX/v1010"
  moduleX_020 "moduleX/v1020"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The ideal solution here is to submit an upstream PR to module `A` to make it compatible with `X v0.2.0`, and then update your own module to use the fixed version of module `A`.

If you need to temporarily slot in a fix to module `A` while you are waiting for the upstream maintainer to respond to the PR, you can do that using a `replace` directive. (See https://golang.org/doc/modules/managing-dependencies#tmp_11 for more detail.)